# How to use evernote sdk with angular 2?

Tags: angular

Searched and searched for documentation for getting notes on evernote through javascript api but the documentation is too old.Want to authenticate and get notes of a user on angular2 but unable to find good docs.

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

The documentation at dev.evernote.com is still current. You can start by [downloading the JavaScript SDK](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/). If you're building an iOS app, then use the JavaScript Quick-start Guide for additional guidance getting set up.

Next I'd read through the "Core Concepts" documentation. The [Overview doc](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/articles/core_concepts.php) might be most helpful, as it explains the NoteStore and how to access it.

As for authentication, you'll need to use the standard OAuth flow. There's a guide for OAuth authentication as well.